# R Metafor forest plot study labels

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I have a forest plot with three subgroups and one level of each subgroup comes from the same study. Within escalc I'm using slab=paste(study) and this places the correct labels in the forest plot, but since studies are repeated they are being ended with authoryear.1, authoryear.2, authoryear.3, etc. The forest plot looks like:

```
Group North
Smith 2021.1
Reed 2019.1

Group Central
Smith 2021.2
Reed 2019.2

Group South
Smith 2021.3
Reed 2019.3
```

What I want is...

```
Group North
Smith 2021
Reed 2019

Group Central
Smith 2021
Reed 2019

Group South
Smith 2021
Reed 2019
```

Comment: Could you please share the data using `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `escalc()` enforces that study labels are unique. But you can use the `slab` argument of the `forest()` function to specify the study labels and they will be used as is.